# Responsive navbar dropdown only opening on hover instead of click

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, responsive

I'm creating a responsive navigation menu using flexbox, problem is for menu options with a dropdown the dropdown shows when I hover over them on a small screen, instead I want it to show only when clicking when on mobile (since hover is not registered on mobile afaik).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBrBv.jpg

This is my code as you see I am using jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nav_dropdown").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
      $(this).nextAll('.nav_dropdown_contents:first').toggleClass('visible');
    });

 
 $(".nav_menu_toggle").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
      $('.nav_link').toggleClass('visible');
    });





});
```

```css
.nav_maincontainer{width:100%; height:50px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 100px; background-color:#004771; position:relative;}

.nav_link{font-size:17px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:100%; width:auto; }

.nav_link:first-child{margin-right:auto;}

.nav_link:nth-child(3){margin-left:auto;}

.nav_dropdown{width:auto; height:100%; position:relative;}

.nav_dropdown_btn{font-size:17px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; height:100%;}

.fa-caret-down{color:white; font-size:10px; margin-left:5px;}

.nav_dropdown_contents{display:none; min-width:200px; flex-direction:column; height:auto; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0px;}

.nav_dropdown_link{padding:15px 10px; background-color:#383838; font-size:15px; color:white; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_toggle{font-size:20px; color:white; display:none; width:50px; height:50px; }

.nav_dropdown:hover .nav_dropdown_contents{ display:flex;}

.nav_link:hover{background-color:#072060;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) 
{
.nav_maincontainer{width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; padding:0px; background-color:#004771; position:relative;}

.nav_link{font-size:16px; width:100%; height:45px; display:none; padding:0px 10px; align-items:center; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); justify-content:flex-start; color:white;}

.nav_dropdown{width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;}

.nav_dropdown_btn{font-size:16px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; height:100%;}

.fa-caret-down{color:white; font-size:10px; margin-left:auto;}

.nav_dropdown_contents{display:none; min-width:100%; flex-direction:column; height:auto; font-size:15px; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;}

.nav_dropdown_link{padding:0px 10px; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; background-color:#383838; color:white; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_toggle{width:100%; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:10px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_text{color:white; margin-right:auto; font-size:16px;}

.fa-bars{color:white; font-size:20px; margin-left:auto;}

.nav_dropdown:hover .nav_dropdown_contents{ display:flex;}

.nav_link:hover{background-color:#072060;}  
}

.flex   {display:flex;}
.visible{display:flex;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav_maincontainer" style="">
    <a class="nav_menu_toggle" href="" onclick="">
        <span class="nav_menu_text">Menu</span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="/home" style="">Home</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="/home" style="">Service</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="/home" style="">Courses</a>
    <div class="nav_dropdown" style="">
        <a href="" class="nav_link" style="">Dropdown 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style=""></i>
        </a>
        <div class="nav_dropdown_contents" style="">
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link" href="#" style="">Dropdown Link 1</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link" href="#" style="">Dropdown Link 1</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link" href="#" style="">Dropdown Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="nav_link" href="/home" style="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the problem is with your nextAll() since you're targeting child elements, not siblings. 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav_dropdown").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).find('.nav_dropdown_contents').toggleClass('visible');
    });


    $(".nav_menu_toggle").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.nav_link').toggleClass('visible');
    });





});
```

CSS (I commented out the hover stuff so you could test a little easier):

```
.nav_maincontainer{width:100%; height:50px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 100px; background-color:#004771; position:relative;}

.nav_link{font-size:17px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:100%; width:auto; }

.nav_link:first-child{margin-right:auto;}

.nav_link:nth-child(3){margin-left:auto;}

.nav_dropdown{width:auto; height:100%; position:relative;}

.nav_dropdown_btn{font-size:17px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; height:100%;}

.fa-caret-down{color:white; font-size:10px; margin-left:5px;}

.nav_dropdown_contents{display:none; min-width:200px; flex-direction:column; height:auto; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0px;}

.nav_dropdown_link{padding:15px 10px; background-color:#383838; font-size:15px; color:white; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_toggle{font-size:20px; color:white; display:none; width:50px; height:50px; }

/* .nav_dropdown:hover .nav_dropdown_contents{ display:flex;} */

.nav_link:hover{background-color:#072060;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) 
{
.nav_maincontainer{width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; padding:0px; background-color:#004771; position:relative;}

.nav_link{font-size:16px; width:100%; height:45px; display:none; padding:0px 10px; align-items:center; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2); justify-content:flex-start; color:white;}

.nav_dropdown{width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;}

.nav_dropdown_btn{font-size:16px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; height:100%;}

.fa-caret-down{color:white; font-size:10px; margin-left:auto;}

.nav_dropdown_contents{display:none; min-width:100%; flex-direction:column; height:auto; font-size:15px; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;}

.nav_dropdown_link{padding:0px 10px; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; background-color:#383838; color:white; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_toggle{width:100%; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:10px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}

.nav_menu_text{color:white; margin-right:auto; font-size:16px;}

.fa-bars{color:white; font-size:20px; margin-left:auto;}

/* .nav_dropdown:hover .nav_dropdown_contents{ display:flex;} */

.nav_link:hover{background-color:#072060;}      
}

.flex   {display:flex;}
.visible{display:flex;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/onxcx0r4/3/

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your CSS which needs fixing. Added comments where fixes are needed.

```
.nav_dropdown {
  width: auto;
  heigh: 100%; // Typo 
  position: relative;
}
.nav_menu_toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%; // Duplicate width
}
.nav_dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    heigh: auto; // Typo
    position: relative;
  }
```

The design solution is not responsive to begin with. The "contact" option is outside the viewport introducing a horizontal scroll. I suggest leveraging 12 grid system and possibly Bootstrap 4 for simplicity.

look in to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for noticing the typos but they didn't really changed anything, I still can't get the dropdown to show when clicking, I also don't understand how it's not responsive, works great when changing screen size.

Comment: Also I heard about bootstrap but I'd rather code it myself since I'm learning